# What is the best way to display inline two paragraphs?

Tags: html, css

I created this code that displays the paragraphs in second line ... is there a better way to do this?

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eyjavedp/)

HTML CODE:

```
<p id="first">Primul paragraf</p>
<p id="second">Al dolea paragraf</p>
```

Code css:

```
    #first
{
width:130px;
background:red;
    display:inline;
    float:left;
}

#second
{
    width:150px;
    background:blue;
    float:right;
    display:inline;
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: what is the question? `display: inline` isn't necessary for floating items.

Comment: if you want to clear use `display:block` without width

Comment: when you want to use "display: inline" should be added to both paragraphs?

Comment: I have update your fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/eyjavedp/1/. I don't know if is what you want

Comment: Asking for “best way” or “better way” is primarily opinion-based, especially when no criteria have been specified.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for two distinct pieces of content to live next to each other, check out [a simple grid layout](http://css-tricks.com/dont-overthink-it-grids/).

If you're trying to mush two distinct pieces of content into one line, then [you're using non-semantic HTML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semantic_HTML), and you should switch to using a different heirarchy of tags to accomplish your content-smushing.

I believe I understand you correctly that you're looking for  - essentially - a two column layout. I strongly recommend the css-tricks "Don't Overthink It Grids" layout, and I'm using a slightly (*slightly*) more complicated grid layout in production sites.